# Do Lutherans and Catholics have the same beliefs regarding the purpose of Confirmation?

Tags: lutheranism, confirmation

As a Catholic, I believe that I received a greater outpouring the Holy Spirit at Confirmation.

> Baptism, the Eucharist, and the sacrament of Confirmation together constitute the "sacraments of Christian initiation," whose unity must be safeguarded. It must be explained to the faithful that the reception of the sacrament of Confirmation is necessary for the completion of baptismal grace. For "by the sacrament of Confirmation, [the baptized] are more perfectly bound to the Church and are **enriched with a special strength of the Holy Spirit**. Hence they are, as true witnesses of Christ, more strictly obliged to spread and defend the faith by word and deed." - [Catechism of the Catholic Church](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c1a2.htm)

However, my understanding is that for Lutherans, confirmation is a more of an affirmation of baptism.

Do Lutherans and Catholics have the same beliefs regarding the purpose of Confirmation?

Comment: I think you mean, "As a Catholic, the Church teaches that at confirmation, we receive an outpouring of the gifts of the Holy Spirit."   Catholic's receive the Holy Spirit, in some manor, from all the Sacraments though out our lives.  Now what we do with that free gift, that is another issue.

Comment: Craig, I am pretty sure that Marc has the right of it.  When were you confirmed?

Comment: @curiousdannii I think that's the result of 1-dimensional catechesis (and I'm guilty of it too).  It's easier to teach kids who are preparing for Confirmation that they receive the Holy Spirit at Confirmation; I think it makes 'em think they didn't already receive the same Spirit at Baptism.

Comment: @PeterTurner How is it "easy" to teach such a blatant mistake? As a Protestant I'd call it one of the greatest heresies.

Comment: Given the feedback on this question, I did some more research and learned that indeed, Confirmation is the outpouring of gifts from the Holy Spirit. I suspect my CCD education was over-simplified, referring to @PeterTurner's comment. I've edited my question to more accurately reflect my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Lutheran faith confirmation is not a sacrament as it is for Catholics.  According to the book of Concord Article XIII(VII) confirmation does not meet the criteria which make a sacrament as it is not required by Gods direct command nor is there a clear promise of grace associated with it.  I would say the caveat exists that it is at conformation where people first receive communion as it marks that they now have fellowship with other Lutherans of their denomination.